# size of derived class

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I am new to C++ programming, in the below code i am using virtual inheritance so size of derived class is showing 24 bytes but i am not getting how it is so please help me how exactly it is.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseClass
{
      private : int a, b;
      public :
  BaseClass()
  {
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
  }
  virtual int area()
  {
    return 0;
  }
};

class DerivedClass1 : virtual public BaseClass
{
  int x;
      public:
  virtual void simple()
  {
    cout << "inside simple" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
   DerivedClass1 Obj;
   cout << sizeof(Obj) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Virtual inheritance doesn't do anything useful in this case. Virtual inheritance is usually used when there's a diamond-shaped inheritance pattern - A inherits B and C, B and C both inherit D. If B and C both inherit D using virtual inheritance, A only inherits one shared "copy" of D - otherwise it inherits two separate "copies" of D. Here, there's only one base, inherited only via one route, so there's no possibility of sharing bases. Memory layout may still differ for virtual vs. non-virtual inheritance even where there's no immediate point to it, but probably not in this case.

Comment: yeah Steve i know virtual inheritance is not doing anything here..but i am just checking what is the size of Derived Class if i do like this ...so please me in the way of that ..

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh - I think James already got that right. The only thing is that the layout is only *accidentally* the same as for non-virtual inheritance - the "shared" part (`BaseClass::a` and `BaseClass::b`) presumably being found via an `offsetof` held in the virtual table rather than by knowing the offset at compile-time.

Comment: @jogojapan Certainly a duplicate, but not an **exact** duplicate, right? And by the the way, hi.

Comment: @JamesBrock Oh hi!.. I said duplicate on the grounds that it asks for the same information than the other question (apart from the specific numbers involved). Perhaps I am wrong..?

Comment: @jogojapan Oh, you're probably right ;)

Comment: @JamesBrock btw I had upvoted your answer nevertheless. The details are certainly implementation-defined, but the answer explains the issues at hand well -- should the question be closed and perhaps merged with the duplicate one, the answer will continue to be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you're compiling as 64-bit? In that case, your DerivedClass1 will probably be laid out in memory with this arrangement of bytes:

```
offset     size    type
0          8       pointer to virtual function table
8          4       int BaseClass::a
12         4       int BaseClass::b
16         4       int DerivedClass1::x
20         4       filler, so that the total size of this class is an even number of 64-bit (8-byte) words
```

The pointer to virtual function table is silently added to your class by the C++ compiler for any class that is part of a class inheritance hierarchy containing any virtual functions.

Comment: no i am not compiling as 64-bit ..i am compiling as 32-bit but still it shows 24 bytes ...why like that ..

Comment: @John5342 - another way to handle the same thing is to have an `offsetof` stored in the virtual table, so you can figure out the offset to the chunk that's inherited from a particular base at run-time. This is perhaps slightly more complex, but reduces per-instance size overheads. It's also the only way I can think of to explain the `sizeof` value, so I think James is right.

Comment: @John5342 - `sizeof(DerivedClass1)` must include `BaseClass::a` and `BaseClass::b`. Those members must exist. The fact that their relative positions may be different in any class that inherits from `DerivedClass1` doesn't change that. `sizeof(DerivedClass1)` includes all members, even those inherited via virtual inheritance. If class `A` inherits `BaseClass` via two different routes, both with virtual inheritance, `sizeof(A)` will also include space for *one* copy of the members from `BaseClass`.

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh If you're compiling to a 32-bit target, I would expect DerivedClass1 to be 16 bytes: One 4-byte vft pointer, and three 4-byte ints. No filler, because the class would already be aligned to 4-byte words.

Comment: @John5342 - also, in James' layout, `BaseClass` *is* before everything else. Even the virtual pointer can be considered part of the `BaseClass` chunk.

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh Would you please amend your question to include your operating system, compiler, and the command line you use to compile?